# What would happen if I insert element to vector inside a iterator loop?

Tags: c++

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int>  v(a, a + sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) ); // v:1 2 3 4
for(vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) {
    if (*it == 2)
        v.insert(v.begin(), 0); // v:0 1 2 3 4
}
```

The question is after the insertion, does `it` still point to `2`? or change to `1`? or anything else? I got a really weird output and couldn't figure out.

Thank you!

Comment: you may be interested in [iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: Well modifying the vector changes also the iterator so iterating through it is no longer possible, because elements like `v.begin()` and `v.end()` loose consistency and I guess get deallocated...

Comment: In this case, iterating isn't possible because all iterator after the insertion point are invalidated. The iterators before are still valid but you insert a first element so there is no chance.